# Why is this duplicate column error appearing?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, postgresql, activerecord

I am trying to add a new column `active` to my table `students`.

I ran `rails g migration add_active_to_students active:boolean` to generate this migration:

```
class AddActiveToStudents < ActiveRecord::Migration[5.0]
  def change
    add_column :students, :active, :boolean, default: true
  end
end
```

But when I run `rails db:migrate` I get this error:

> PG::DuplicateColumn: ERROR:  column "active" of relation "students" already exists
>   : ALTER TABLE "students" ADD "active" boolean DEFAULT 't'`

As you can see there is not actually an `active` column in `students`:

```
create_table "students", force: :cascade do |t|
    t.integer  "club_id"
    t.string   "email"
    t.string   "address_line_1"
    t.string   "address_line_2"
    t.string   "city"
    t.string   "state"
    t.integer  "postcode"
    t.string   "phone1"
    t.string   "phone2"
    t.string   "first_name"
    t.string   "last_name"
    t.date     "dob"
    t.datetime "created_at",      null: false
    t.datetime "updated_at",      null: false
    t.string   "picture"
    t.integer  "payment_plan_id"
    t.string   "parent1"
    t.string   "parent2"
    t.string   "size"
    t.text     "notes"
    t.index ["club_id"], name: "index_students_on_club_id", using: :btree
  end
```

So why would I be getting this error?

Comment: Remove the migration file you created, then run `rails db:migrate` and inspect your db/schema.rb again (it should re-generate a new one). If you're missing a migration file that should have created that column (you should check) then you may have created it some other way; (manually, in another branch when testing and you forgot to roll back) so consider that you may need to undo what you did (delete column manually, switch back to other branch and roll back) so you can create the migration as you need

Answer (score 14, accepted):

I followed the steps that @demir posted and found that, yes, the column was in the database without being listed in the schema. `ALTER TABLE students DROP COLUMN active` did not give an error message however it also didn't remove the column.

In the end I removed it by:

1. Entering the console

`rails console`

2. Deleting the column

`ActiveRecord::Base.connection.remove_column :students, :active`

Comment: Thanks man, this was really helpful! I was having a hard time...

Answer (score 2):

You may have added it somehow. Have you checked the PG database? Connect to the application database and see if there is an active field.

1. List databases

   ```
   \l
   ```
2. Connect database

   ```
   \c your_app_database_name
   ```
3. List table columns

   ```
   \d+ students
   ```
4. Check active field, remove it if exist.

   ```
   ALTER TABLE students DROP COLUMN active
   ```

Answer (score 1):

You have this column in your DB, but it wasn't dumped to your `schema.rb`. Maybe a migration was stopped after it added the column, but before it wrote to `schema.rb`?

You can remove this column manually, running `rails dbconsole` and then:

```
ALTER TABLE students DROP COLUMN active
```

Answer (score 0):

You can follow the above solutions i.e. drop the column from DB first and then run the migration. Most probably what has happened is, you created and run some migration but later deleted that migration file without doing a `db:rollback`.

One more option that you can consider is to put a conditional migration like:

```
class AddActiveToStudents < ActiveRecord::Migration[5.0]
  def change
    unless column_exists? :students, :active
      add_column :students, :active, :boolean, default: true
    end
  end
end
```

Comment: Id it would be the case, the column would be present om schema.rb